# ssh change default authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, router, cisco

when I try to access to a router with ssh enabled, it says this:

```
Unable to negotiate with 101.16.16.2 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

To resolve this problem, I can execute the following command to force ssh to use the authentication method that the router uses

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c aes128-cbc -l <username> 10.10.10.5
```

Is there any way to configure ssh to use that authentication by default. Thanks

Comment: A router alone wouldn't care about SSH authentication; it would just pass the packets on to the next host according to its routing table. You appear to be using the `ProxyCommand` option somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the `~/.ssh/config` and add the information of the host IP and ciphers. In your case, it should state:

```
Host 101.16.16.2
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    Ciphers aes128-cbc
```